# Linux: logoff the user after its serial console terminated

Tags: linux, bash, console, serial

I connected to Linux (in the case here, I used Ubuntu 1604) by **serial console**.

Now, the serial console is closed (terminated), but, when I connect back to the serial port again I saw all the sessions are left there.

How can I configure Linux to detect my serial console is terminated and logout me automatically?

I expect the application which monitor the serial port should send `SIGHUP` to `bash` or someone else and kill/stop all processes and close my session.

Thanks!

Comment: You will probably want to check https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125261/98424

Answer (score 1):

You are not guaranteed to have means to figure out whether the serial console is in use or not.

Because of that, your next-closest answer is to use your shells builtin features to auto logout when the shell is not in use (based on inactivity).

```
$ export TMOUT=600
```

On most system that means you want to edit your `.bashrc` and add that line there.

That would logoff serial console users if they stay idle for more than  600 seconds (10 minutes) - likely the case when they unplug their serial console - but not preventing unauthorized access should someone else plugin theirs meanwhile.